# How load component after First Contentful Paint or first elements in Vue.js or Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js

My goal is best solution the **First Contentful Paint** with Vue.js or Nuxt.js

I think the best solution is to load component with import after when the first elements are loaded.

I don't know if is best solution, I would like to hear your opinions.

What is best way to code?

**Trying:**

The file is loaded with `app.js`, how load only **a time** when I set to `true`?

[image: devtools]

```html
<template>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <!-- First content here -->

  <foo v-if="documentLoaded" />
</template>
```

```js
mounted() {
  document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      console.log('Page completed with image and files!')

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.documentLoaded = true
      }, 2000);

    }
  }
},
components: {
  Foo: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "component-foo" */ '~/components/foo')
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using requesting that file in `index.html` as well. Do you need it there?

Comment: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration maybe this will help you

Comment: @Aldarund This plugin loads even when it was not visible

Answer (score 1):

You can define when a dynamically loaded component is effectively loaded using import like you said, in conjunction with v-if on the component.

```
<mycomp v-if="readyStateComplete"/>

//readyStateComplete is a boolean from data.
```

Setting the boolean to true will trigger the loading, then init and display of the component.

```
mounted() {
  document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      console.log('Page completed with image and files!')

      // HOW LOAD COMPONENTS HERE?
      this.readyStateComplete = true

    }
  }
},
```

If you want your component to be loaded the same time as the image, but just displayed after, use v-show instead of v-if.

Comment: But the component `mycomp` load file (.js) when show?

Comment: With show It load the file during init of parent component, yes. Check dev tool and you will see.

Comment: Globally with import promise, child component is loaded when it is needed in the parent template. It's only with a falsey initial condition in v-if that a component is not needed in the template, until that condition become true.

Comment: With webpack, use webpackchunkname inside import statement to see it better in the console.

Comment: You have everything in this response to do the trick. There is a problem with your console screnshot. You may have only one load oh component-foo. Check if you give the same webpackchunkname to two components, or maybe you load it in a inline src tag in index.html

Comment: And i think it will be better without settimeout, and to rely on elements events instead of doc ones.